# Rotating the image of a picturebox that only has an ImageLocation

Tags: image, rotation, picturebox

I have a card game program that when a card gets discarded and is found to be a certain type of card, it goes into my DefeatedChars pile, which is just a PictureBox named DefeatedChars. Currently all my images are loaded during runtime using ImageLocation which is the string of some website that stores all the card images. I want to know how to load this string to the PictureBox's Image property so I can rotate it because trying to rotate gives me a null pointer exception because Image is nothing, at least I think that's why. I do know through debugging that when DefeatedChars.Image is nothing. My question is, is there a way to rotate the ImageLocation after it's been loaded or is there a way to move the image found at the ImageLocation into the image property. Ultimately, when I'm done with the game, I want the image found at the image location to be stored somewhere locally so that if the website changes, which it does, the cards will retain their images and properties, but that's a question for later down the road. Here is the code I am stuck at that gives me a null pointer exception. I'm coding in Visual Studio.

DefeatedChars.ImageLocation = tempCard.ImageLocation
DefeatedChars.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this...
DefeatedChars.Image = Image.FromFile(tempCard.ImageLocation)
But I ran into a "URI formats are not supported error". Then I found this little gem on the internet, which replaces the first line of code above.

DefeatedChars.Image = Image.FromStream(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(tempCard.ImageLocation).GetResponse().GetResponseStream())

It turns the URL into a stream so it can be used by the Image property and it works like a charm.